# Minimumn launch.json inside .vscode directory for running main class of a maven project (with `F5`)

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, launch

I've looked at [vscode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging) but I have not yet managed to run a maven project's main class just by hitting `F5`.

Let's say that my project contains a class inside `src/main/java/mypackage/Main.java` with a `main` method inside (which accesses `src/main/java/mypackage/MyClass2.java` )

What would be the `.vscode/launch.json` file that i should commit with my project in order to able to be able to run it from vscode just by hitting `F5`?

Also what are the minimum extensions that I should install in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 'Java Extension Pack' extension.
And you should set 'mainClass' variable in launch.json file.
From the information you have given out, you can set like this: '${workspaceFolder}/src/main/java/mypackage/Main.java'.
as the ${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code.